# d3 graph in a div section

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I am plotting multiple graphs in one HTML page and I want to add the second graph in a div section to have more proper looking charts.

This is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uwF85mlnrNKWyNtQvTUU?p=preview) I created.

Can someone tell me how I can change the code below to have it in a div section?

**HTML**:

```
 <svg width="1200" height="550"></svg>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 70, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 20},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Comment: I don't think you have the full code here, and the plunker already appends it to a div.

You should just be able to do

`var div = document.querySelector('div')`
`div.appendChild(svg)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but no, it's not a div. In fact, I want to add the second graph in a div. It is SVG now.

Comment: Are you meaning a canvas element instead of an svg output? There's definitely a wrapper there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `script.js` you append the svg to an existing div like so:

`var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")`

So, do the same in the file `positiveChart.js`.

Append the svg to an existing div like so (while also giving the svg element the height and width attributes that you had in `index.html`):

`var svg = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg").attr("width", 1200).attr("height", 550)`

Then in `index.html` make a div `<div id="chart1"></div>` that can be selected by d3 to append your 2nd svg.

[Forked plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TMp2rt1SjpSNE3AkjlgZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot.